# Draw the perimeter MapView ios

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5, mkmapview

I'm trying to implement something like that. I will draw locations on the map, and will give the user the option to mark the area he wants to list the points only inside where he designed.

It would be something like the attached image.

[I could not upload the image, I posted it here](http://i48.tinypic.com/dg79yo.png)

ie after he has drawn an area on the map, I show the points where he scored within

Answer (score 0):

Why not just let the user zoom in so the area they want to see fills the screen?

Comment: It is a property search, with that I would consume less database I believe, and is a requirement of the client.

Comment: After the user has zoomed in you fetch just the points that are within the view, effectively using the visible bounds of the map rather than the hand drawn bounds to limit the search. Otherwise you'll have to determine when the user was dragging their finger on the map to draw your bounds and when they were dragging their finger to move the map. That would probably mean a toggle on screen to lock the map position while the user draws and adding user interface elements is bad if it can be done without them.

Comment: requirement of the customer, because he saw an app that has this tool.